# SonataUserBundle + FOSUserBundle Annotation Issue Doctrine Primary Key Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

Using Symfony 4.1, Sonata User Bundle 4.x, and FOSUserBundle 2.1.2.

I am trying to override the table names for the User and Group tables. I therefore added annotations to the auto generated user and group classes:

```
use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup as BaseGroup;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * This file has been generated by the SonataEasyExtendsBundle.
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="aegis_group")
 * @link https://sonata-project.org/easy-extends 
 * References:
 * @link http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/working-with-objects/en
 */
class Group extends BaseGroup
{
    /**     
     * @ORM\Id      
     * @var int $id
     */
    protected $id;

   /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }    
}
```

I then modified doctrine.yaml to factor in these annotations:

```
        mappings:                    
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: App
                FOSUserBundle: ~                                          
                ApplicationSonataUserBundle: 
                    type: annotation
                SonataUserBundle: ~
```

However, when I run migrations, doctrine gives me an error:

> In MappingException.php line 46:
>
> No identifier/primary key specified for Entity
>   "App\Application\Sonata\User   Bundle\Entity\Group" sub class of
>   "Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup". Every Entity must have an
>   identifier/primary key.

**How to fix this issue, so that I can use my own custom table names ? All I want to do is to change the database table names, this should not be this involved.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out an XML orm file is generated by the SonataEasyExtendsBundle, in directory Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine folder. One should modify this file (User.orm.xml) to make changes to the table config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                  http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User" table="aegis_user">

        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>

    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you forgot namespace in your class.

Second: Try to add a strategy and a column for your primary key like

```
/**
 * @var int $id
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
```